# How to pronounce "论"

Tags: vocabulary, pronunciation

I"ve been trying to figure out the tones for the character 论. It seems like it is fourth tone in 讨论. However, in something like 一概而论 I'm not entirely sure. Is this a taiwan/Mainland division? Or is it decided on a word by word basis?

Comment: the 论s are both (讨论 and 一概而论) fourth tone....what's the problem?!

Comment: I am also curious why the confusion? Which other tone have you encountered?

Comment: You might hear a 轻声 lun in 讨论. That's all I can think of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the 4th in 一概而论, both regions:

Check. e.g.:

- Mainland: [在线新华字典](http://xh.5156edu.com/html4/12340.html)
- Taiwan: [教育部重编国语字典](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/newDict/dict.sh?cond=%A4%40%B7%A7%A6%D3%BD%D7&pieceLen=50&fld=1&cat=&ukey=989037169&serial=1&recNo=44&op=&imgFont=1)

(Both URLs point to the '一概而论' entry)

论 does have a 2nd tone reading, but 论语 seems to be the only where it is used.

Answer (score 6):

Old Pekin dialect (>50 years ago) pronounce it as **lin(4th tone)** and that might be influencing some other dialects.

I am not sure about the situation in TW, but mandarin standard is **lun(4th tone)** except for 论语, habitually **lun (2nd tone)**.

Answer (score 3):

论 ，there are two tones. second tone and fourth.

Mostly，论 is fourth tone.It is a verb.

e.g.  一概而论、讨论

Only in the situation of 论语 ，论 is the second tone.

论语 is an old book writtern by Confucius‘s students,recording what Confucius said!

Answer (score 1):

It should be the 4th tone.

Actually, every "论" has the same meaning is the 4th tone, such as “讨论”(discuss) “理论”(theory).

“论” in the word “论语” is specially the 2nd tone because it doesn't means like that.

When the 论 is the 2nd tone, it should be in classical Chinese and means:

> 1. 说得尽(some thing you want to say can be finished)(is always used  when there is so much thing you want to say but you can hardly finish them.)
> 2. 表达，抒发(Express something you want to.)